# Rises/Stands (up)/Gets up

Tags: word-choice

A bad guy with a gun is hiding behind a table flipped on its side while several police officers are shooting at him from a distance.

Suddenly the bad guy **rises**/**stands**/**stands up**/**gets up** and strides toward the officers while shooting at them.

I know they are similar in meaning, but which one would a native speaker find the more natural choice in this context? And is there one or more of them which would not seem natural here? Thank you.

Comment: get's on his feet (legs) - this is also possible

Comment: or maybe a poetic "lifts himself up"

Comment: maybe "starts up" for a rapid change of stances.

Answer (score 1):

"The bad guy stands up" would be clearest. "Gets up" or "rises" could imply that the bad guy does not stand up completely, but rather to a crouching position just over the table or to another intermediate position.